# How do calculate not emty set levels of function $f$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be defined as follows:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{4}}&\text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0&\text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

I put for $x=rcos\phi$ and $y=rsin\phi$ and the end I get
$\frac{r^3cos\phi sin^2\phi}{r^2cos^2\phi+r^4sin^4\phi}$
What to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

$$ - \frac{1}{2} \leq  \frac{uv}{u^2 + v^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}   $$
because
$$ (u-v)^2 \geq 0 $$ and
$$ (u+v)^2 \geq 0 $$

The stuff above is just, well, true. If you then take $$ u = x, \; \; v = y^2 $$ you get something useful.

Comment: what is u what v?

Comment: @Laja, anything you like, as long as they stand for real numbers

Comment: but what meaning has (u-v)^2>0

Comment: why you use 1/2